# Flutter - ConstrainedBox does not work if it contains a Row() or a Column()

Tags: flutter

The title pretty much says it all - I am finding that the ConstrainedBox widget does not work if it contains a Row or a Column.

Here is my code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Testing ConstrainedBox'),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 25),
        children: [
          ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 600),
            child: Card(
              color: Colors.yellow,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 15),
                child: Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        height: 50,
                        width: 50,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: const <Widget>[
                          Text('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.'),
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                            child: Text('Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.'),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                            child: Text('Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.'),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If you run this and make the window bigger then the "maxWidth" does not apply and instead the Card grows to the full width available to it.

I tried putting the ConstrainedBox inside the Row but that makes no difference, presumably because of the Col. Note also that getting rid of the ListView does not change anything.

Anyone got any idea why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ListView`is forcing its children to have max width. You can wrap the children with another widget that will cover it.

```dart
body: ListView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 25),
        children: [
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 600),
```

Comment: No, that doesn't work. Note that if I remove the ListBox altogether I get the same problem

Comment: can you try `flutter clean` and rebuild the app.

Comment: well that does seem to fixed it, but why did I need to clean and then rebuild my packages - is this something that has just been fixed and I just happened to have an old version of the "material" package (or maybe another package) with a bug?

Comment: ig sometime cache issue on debug mode,

Comment: OMG that is horrible! thanks for your advice :-)